# Trouble reading file, program looks good not understanding why its outputting null

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, inputstream

Hey guys I'm trying to read in a file which I have done many times before, but It keeps outputting "null" for however many lines of code exist in the .

```html
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] item = new String[25];
   Scanner fileInput;
   File inFile = new File("dictionary.txt");
    try {
    fileInput = new Scanner(inFile);
    int newItem = 0;
    while (fileInput.hasNext())
    {
      item[newItem++] = fileInput.nextLine();
      System.out.println(item[newItem]);
    }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e); }
```

txt file. please help.

Comment: What exactly is the file input? Is `fileInput != null`?

Comment: yes it will always be != too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment `newItem` and then you print `item[newItem]`. It always return null because you have not written anything yet in `item` for the new index.

Try:

```
while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
    item[newItem] = fileInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println(item[newItem]);
    newItem++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of newItem++, which returns the value and **then** increments it.

So, you start by setting item[x] = ...; - but then print out item[x+1];

Comment: If I set Item to X than I would have to use a for loop and I did not think I need that

Comment: It's enough to print out item[newItem - 1]; Or start with newItem = -1 and then use item[++newItem] =...;